# Moving of shortcut icons programmatically

Tags: c#, file-io, shortcut-file

In my Windows 7 PC, I have some applications installed which has desktop shortcuts. My desktop has multiple user accounts. For some applications I had shortcuts placed only on my admin desktop. I wanted them available for other users too. So I wrote a program that moves the admin desktop icon to public desktop. I did something like this:

```
File.Move(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory) + @"\MyShortcut.lnk", System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonDesktopDirectory) + @"\MyShortcut.lnk");
```

Now I have those shortcut files seen in all other accounts. It still works good in admin account. But in other accounts they no more behave like shortcut. The shortcut tab in properties itself is not seen (in other accounts). I did the same manually and it works like a champ. Why would this happen any other way to accomplish the same programmatically?